# Add total row to the top of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I've been trying to find how to add the 'total' row to the top of the dataframe, rather than the bottom, but haven't managed to - I need to reference the row by a label rather than by using iloc or a numerical index since the index is qualitative and the number of rows will vary.

I've appended the row to the bottom of the dataframe using the following code:

```
df.loc['Total',:] = df.sum(axis=0)
```

Is there any way I can move the row to the top by just referencing 'Total' rather than doing a whole bunch of resetting and setting indices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df = df.loc['Total',:].append(df.loc['Total',:]).iloc[:-1]` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `append`

```
df.sum(axis=0).to_frame('Total').T.append(df)
```

Comment: @MathsicalStudies: you are welcome. Glad I could help :)